# Angular: Convert parameter String inside ng-click

Tags: angularjs, string, int, angularjs-ng-click

is it possible to convert `String` to `int` inside ng-click?

I have this data

```
$scope.cartList = [{ number: "1"}];
```

So in my view i just call `number` using ng-repeat( `ng-repeat="cart in cartList"`). I use `number` for increment by using ng-click.

```
<button data-ng-click="increment = 0 + cart.number></button>
<span>{{increment}}</span>
```

So here I got problem during calculation, I know `cart.number` is `String` but is there any way to convert `cart.number` to `int` inside `ng-click`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Your logic is wrong** . you are calculated with 0, it can't increase the count . So you should calculate with latest increment value instead of 0.

Try this

```
<button data-ng-click="increment = increment + parseInt(cart.number)"></button>
<span>{{increment}}</span>
```

Please assign `parseInt` in a scope object in controller. then use that in button

```
$scope.parseInt = parseInt;
```

### You can check the demo here:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
function Homecontroller($scope)
{
$scope.cartList = [{ number: "1"}];
$scope.parseInt=parseInt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Homecontroller">
<button data-ng-click="increment = increment + parseInt(cartList[0].number)">increase</button>
<span>{{increment}}</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: then?  I already try to use this `Number(cart.number)` as advice by Saurabh. but still not working

Comment: ahh ok2, but I have update my code but `cart.number` is still `String`. `Number(cart.number)` not convert `String` to `int`

Comment: still not working man. the `{{increment}}` still not increase

Comment: It's working to me. added code on snippet. check it now

Comment: `app.filter('numb', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return parseInt(input, 10);
    };
});`  is this still using? seams like you are not using `numb` in view button

Comment: That is another option. I have using `parseInt`. You can check it on the snippet right?

Comment: Mark it is an answer, if you got the result :) :)

Answer (score 0):

parseInt is used to convert string to int but it cannot be used inside angular expression. So, you can create a function which converts your string to an integer value and then do the desired computation.

In your controller:

```
$scope.doIncrement = function(cartNumber) { 
  $scope.increment = 0 + parseInt(cartNumber); 
}
```

In your view:

```
<button ng-click="doIncrement(cart.number)"></button>
<span>{{increment}}</span>
```

Comment: well I think he wants to do it in view only, Not in controller.

Comment: yes I know, just try my luck. I don't want to do it in controller, because my project now most of calculation in view for some reason. is there any way how to convert `number` to `int` ?